# Autorize.net issue in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, error, authorize.net

I have enable Authorize.net as a payment method in magento 2.3.3
I have entered all corrects details in backend. https://prnt.sc/tiu0ue
Environment is set to Sandbox. My sandbox account is also in Test mode.
During checkout after i enter card details and click on place order, i am getting error as " An error occurred during processing. Please try again."
Have anybody come across this error? Please help.

Comment: are you sure that the network of .net auth is not dowm? earlier also it happened and the reason was this only

Comment: I checked it is not down